# Jquery Ui Tabs not working

Tags: theme-development

jquery ui tabs not working in Wordpress, i have added this function to my functions.php

```
if( !is_admin()){
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"));
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
   wp_register_script('jquery-ui',("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"));
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');
}
```

And header.php

```
<ul class="menu-nav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'menu')); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using hosted versions of jQuery and jQuery UI when WordPress has local versions?

To use tabs you need to add the tabs register code in a js file or in your footer (via the wp_footer filter) in your functions.php

e.g.

```
function wpse203799_footerscript(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>
<?php
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse203799_footerscript', '30' );
```

Comment: i Have script.js file, with this code http://pastebin.com/YM7siLuz,

Comment: check the browser error log, that will be able to tell you if you have any issues, also check the source to see if the jquery and jquery ui scripts are actually working

Comment: they are working, its happens when i remove <li> elements from <ul> and put <?php wp_nav_menu(array(       'theme_location' => 'menu')); ?>

Comment: check the wp_nav_menu codex as by default it adds a div and a ul around the menu, you need to use container and items wrap to remove these.